# Homotopical equivalence of complexes

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $f : C_{\bullet} \to D_{\bullet} $ be a chain map (in the category of $R$-Mod, for example) and suppose  that $f_ {*}: H_ { n}(C_{\bullet}) \simeq H_ {n}(D_{\bullet})$ is invertible for all $n$. (Here $H_ {n}()$ is the homology of the complex and $f_ {*}$ is the induced map.) Is $f$ invertible up to chain homotopy, i.e., is $f$ a homotopical equivalence ?

I think the answer is no, but I couldn't find a counterexample.

Comment: No in general, but it is true for hereditary algebras.  So you can try to find a counterexample when $R$ is, for example, self-injective, e.g. $R= k[X]/(X^2)$.

Comment: You have defined the notion of **quasi-isomorphism**. Every chain homotopy equivalence is a quasi-isomorphism but not vice versa.

Comment: Zhen Lin do you know where I can find a counterexample ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $C_*$ is an acyclic (i.e. exact) complex, then the unique morphism $0 \to C_*$ is a quasi-isomorphism (i.e. induces isomorphisms on homology groups), but it is a homotopy equivalence iff $C_*$ is split exact. There are lots of acyclic complexes which are not split exact, for example $\dotsc  \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb{Z}/4 \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb{Z}/4 \xrightarrow{2} \dotsc$ in $\mathsf{Mod}(\mathbb{Z}/4)$. On the other hand, every bounded below acyclic complex of free $R$-modules is split exact. See the first pages of any book on homological algebra for these basics.